# How do I assign a string as a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: gnome

I'd like to assign a frequently used string to a shortcut key, so when I press it, it types it in whatever application I'm in. So for example, when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, it types "This is wonderful!" in whatever Gnome app I'm in at that time.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer - `autokey`. This lets you set up shortcuts that can be triggered either by a hot key, or simply typing an abbreviation. I've already added automatic replacement for the common mispellings I make, like replacing "hte" with "the".

You can install autokey with with synaptic package manager, for either KDE or GNOME. For Ubuntu 14.04 and newer, [the package is `autokey-gtk`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=autokey).

I'm a long time Ubuntu user, and I'm kicking myself for missing out on this awesome little app until now.