# Possible to have "yes" as a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Many times a day, I have to type the word `yes`. Is it possible to have it as a shortcut on <kbd>F12</kbd>?

I have seen `gnee` and `xmacro` but they seem very complicated to use and over powered for my purpose.

Comment: Does autokey work for you? [Gnome Keyboard Shortcuts - type string](http://askubuntu.com/q/167761/88802)

Comment: @gertvdijk perfect! Just what I was looking for. Post it, and I will accept it =)

Comment: @SandraSchlichting The answer is already there. I'm voting to close it for being a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Closed as dupe from previous, regards.