# Can I use a custom shortcut to echo a letter or string?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

What I want is when I type something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it echoes "5" (Just as an example).
Like I go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts click the "+" and I type in the name of the shortcut and then I write the command.
In terminal I can write (Just an example):
    `echo ᚠ`
or I could write (again just an example):
    `cat Desktop/letter.txt`

The "echo" command just echoes the letter.
The "cat" command echoes the contents of the file.
But it seems to only work if I write it in the terminal (The command works. Not the shortcut).

How can I create a shortcut that echoes/prints a letter on where I want to write it so I don't have to write unicode like `U+16a1` or something but only have to press ALT or CTRL and a letter?

I have 13.04

Comment: Does [AutoKey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/autokey-gtk/) work for you? See this (possible duplicate) Q: [How do I assign a string as a keyboard shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/q/167761/88802)

Comment: Any suggestions how to solve this problem without ```AutoKey``` on Ubuntu 14.04?